# PHP Splitting data into 2 columns into an html table not working

Tags: php, html

Hey guys I'm back and I feel like I'm making a really stupid error in my code but I can't seem to find it. What I am trying to do is split data retrieved from a mysql table into two columns inside an html table. So far I got it working...sort of. The problem I am having is the data keeps replicating to both rows in the table versus being an individual entry in each cell. I have used googled and searched these forms and can't seem to see where I am making the error. Below is the code

```
// Build the table
echo '
<table>
<tr>
';

// Build the headers
for ($x = '1'; $x <= '2'; $x++)
echo '

<td>Truck</td>
<td>Home Base</td>
<td>Client</td>
<td>Job Details</td>
<td>Crew</td>
 ';

 // Close off headers
 echo '</tr>';

 // Fetch the table contents if the rigs are active
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($truck_full_query)) {

for ($y = '1'; $y <= '1'; $y++):
    echo '<tr>';
        for ($z = '1'; $z <= '2'; $z++):
                    echo '<td>' . $row['model'] . ' #' . $row['position'] . '<br>' . $row['unit_number'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['dispatch_location'] . '</td>';
                    // Get client information
            echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
            // Get Job Details
            echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
            // Get Crew
            echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
                endfor;
    echo '</tr>';
    endfor;
      }
     // Close table
    echo '</table>';
```

Comment: `for ($y = '1'; $y <= '1'; $y++):` what's this for?

Comment: More or less just me fiddling trying to get this to work. Did a straight copy and paste.

Comment: cargo-cult programming warning: `for($y = '1'; $<= '1'` ...)`. for loops work on integers, not strings. and whye ven bother with a loop when you're only doing a SINGLE iteration?

Comment: @MarcB it works on strings too. But the question is **what for**?

Comment: where did you copy and paste `$y = '1'` from?  i would actually be interested in looking at the rest of the code there.

Comment: Oddly I got the idea from off of this site while looking on another question but I didnt want to necro an old question/answer. I removed it though from the code because it really doesnt serve a purpose. Originally I was using it to try and loop through TRs because I was having other problems with how the data was being displayed. But now its all working except for this single display problem of the data replicating from one column to the next =\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Build the table
echo '<table><tr>';

// Build the headers
echo '<td>Truck</td><td>Home Base</td><td>Client</td><td>Job Details</td><td>Crew</td>';   
echo '<td>Truck</td><td>Home Base</td><td>Client</td><td>Job Details</td><td>Crew</td>';
echo '</tr>';

$data = mysqli_fetch_all($truck_full_query);
$i = 0;
$t = sizeof($data);
for (; $i < $t; $i += 2) {
    echo '<tr>';
    $left_row = $data[$i];
    echo '<td>' . $left_row['model'] .'</td><td>...</td><td>...</td><td>...</td><td>...</td>';
    $right_row = $data[$i + 1];
    echo '<td>' . $right_row['model'] .'</td><td>...</td><td>...</td><td>...</td><td>...</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>
```

And don't forget to check if the last `$right_row` exists.

Comment: Looks like this might work but I'm getting a mysqli_fetch_all() error so I might need to play with it a bit to get it to work.

Comment: Still no luck getting it to work, but I'll keep fidgeting with it after supper.